# Wordpress permalinks not working on Webmin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, centos, permalinks, webmin

I have a Webmin, which is CentOS server, for hosting Wordpress sites.

But my permalinks are not working. I have give a persmisions to Wordpress, so I can control permalinks from WP. 
WP saves a configuration to .htaccess and also all link in my menu change to permalinks I choose, but ofter click on those links, I get "Not found" error.

If I switch WP back to no permalinks, everything works ok again.

Actually, I don't have any idea, what else can I try, and why this is not working. But I suppose there is some setting on the server itself, because, this is not working on any my site on this same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if your apache server has mod_rewrite extension enabled.
That extension is managed short/permalinks for websites like Wordpress.

You can check it by creating short file 'phpinfo.php' in the wordpress folder:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Navigate to the http://yourwebsite.com/phpinfo.php and look for the 'mod_rewrite' in the output.

If you can't find it you need to setup it first, take a look [here](http://dev.antoinesolutions.com/apache-server/mod_rewrite).